# How to add configurations to Xcode?

Tags: xcode, configuration

There are no other way, I search a lot. In XCode 3 this is easy, but now..

In the screen above, I have the **Build Configuration**, so I can chose if I want:

- Debug
- Release

[image: the screen]

This 2 kind of config, have their own config in "Build Settings" tabs (in targets config). To create I third one, the **Distribution**, reading [here,](http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action) it show this image in XCode 3 [image: boring xcode 3]

**Where I can do the same in XCode 4????**

edit->
Only create a new Schema didn't work, like this is a config in "Build Settings" tag of Targets. I can chose a config for "Debug" and "Release", but, and for I third one?

[image]

Comment: [iPhone - how to change the build configuration to distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8804248/194544)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Have a look at the project settings. There is a `+` button that you can use to add to configurations here.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but it not create what I want. In "Build Settings" of targets, you can config things when you run in Debug and Release. I only need a third one. If i create a new scheme, I still have this two config only.

Comment: You are correct... I didn't find it... The transition to XCode 4 is so boring... :(

Answer (score 8):

You don't need it.

Make sure you check the following list before you Archive:

- In Edit Scheme: Select Release as Build Configuration for Archive,
- In Project Build Setting: Set Entitlements.plist and your Distribution code signing for Release scheme,
- In Entitlements.plist: Set No to ‘can be debugged’.

Then archive and share with your ad-hoc provisioning or submit with distribution provisioning.

Hope this is a comprehensive checklist.

EDIT:

to duplicate an existing configuration:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for reply, the problem isn't how create an Archive, but only put in "Build Settings" a third kind of config. If I create a new schema, I still have the "Debug" and "Release"

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue where I wanted some special behaviour for beta builds

These are the steps I took (mostly an expansion of the answer given by @ZhangChn)

1. Duplicate the Release Configuration and rename it beta.
2. Added a BETA pre-processor macro to the Beta Configuration under build settings.

   - Make other changes to your build configuration here.
3. Go into manage schemes and duplicate the main scheme for my project and rename it to Beta.
4. Edit the new scheme and change the target build configuration to beta (or whatever you named your new build configuration.
5. ...
6. Profit!!!!

Or not, at any rate you should now be able to switch your desired setting simply by changing the scheme you're using instead of mucking about with settings every time.

Comment: ^this    I looked at several ways to do this, and these were the most concise and direct instructions. So, +1, thank you!, and all those other things SO says not to say in the comments.