# XCode4: How can I add distribution configuration?

Tags: xcode4, ios4

I see only Debug and Release configuration. I need to add distribution configuration.

Comment: Answer is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218434/how-to-add-configurations-to-xcode-4

Comment: "Archive" action is the new "build for release" in Apple's brave new Xcode 4 world. Especially if you're distributing on the App Store.

Comment: [iPhone - how to change the build configuration to distribution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8804248/194544)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your project (in the left pane) so that the main pane shows the build settings and all that.

Select your project (not a target), then select Info.

You'll see the listed configurations, Debug and Release. There you can add another one, Distribution, based on any existing configuration. You could also create an Ad Hoc configuration. The advantage here is that in the build configurations you can setup code signing per-configuration in a (nearly) "set and forget" fashion. (I always double check that the certs being used are the ones that should be used, however.)

Here's another tip. Duplicate your main scheme and call it "Distro: My App" and edit the Archive action to use your Distribution configuration (rather than say, Ad Hoc or Release). This way, when you want to build a Distribution archive, you can just switch schemes, rather than having to edit your schemes and then remember to undo that change.

Answer (score 0):

Release is distribution. After you compile it in release you then make an archive. In the Organizer's Archive window you can submit the application using your Distributor Cert and Credentials.

Answer (score 0):

1. Sign into the iOS Provisioning Portal and visit this page http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action
2. Select the "Prepare App" tab
3. Select "Building your Application with Xcode for Distribution." That section provides step by step instructions (with pictures) on creating a Distribution configuration.