# Using different values in different environments in Objective C

Tags: ios

What is the most elegant way to define different values, for constants in my code base, based on the environment in Obj-C

e.g.

```
BASE_URL = http://localhost_ in development environment
BASE_URL = http://myproddomainname in prod/release environment
```

Comment: Add target config to xcode. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218434/how-to-add-configurations-to-xcode-4

Comment: There are a half-dozen different ways to do it.  Mostly, though, you define macro variables in the project, based on whether you're compiling for debug or release.